# Array of file scanners

Tags: java, arrays, file

I'm working on condensing my code.  Right now, I've created 6 file scanners that each read from a separate file (questions1.txt, questions2.txt...).  I've attempted to instead use an array of file scanners like so:

```
Scanner[] file = new Scanner[6];

for(int i = 0; i > file.length; i++) {
    file[i] = new Scanner(new File("questions" + i+1 + ".txt"));
}
```

However, when I try to add the first line from a file to a string, it comes back as null:

```
inLine = file[0].nextLine();
```

Is what I am attempting possible, or does my code have to be revised?

Comment: what's the point of keeping the open scanners.  why not just loop over the integer, and open and close a scanner in the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop never gets executed, because

```
for(int i = 0; i > file.length; i++)
```

should be

```
for(int i = 0; i < file.length; i++)
```

Comment: It's always the least complicated fix.  Thanks!